# How can I generate a full swagger doc for Magento 2 REST API?

Tags: magento-2.1, api, rest-api

I have a fresh Magento 2.1.5 install, and I'd like to access the full swagger spec, like the one published on http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger, but with the `Try it Out!` buttons enabled.

I've accessed my local swagger spec on `http://localhost/magento2/swagger`, but the services list isn't complete, when compared to the published on the Magento site.

Comment: That completely failed, El Ema. The exact same endpoints are the same in both scenarios, whether with or without the access token generated from the process you speak of. NOT ONE single new endpoint becomes available!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139931)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139931)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's actually correct behavior.

You need to generate API credentials in magento backend, authenticate, and insert token like on the image below:
[image: token]

Token can be obtained from swagger web interface calling **integrationAdminTokenServiceV1**
or you can authenticate use curl:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://your-host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token -d '{ "username": "yourUsername", "password": "yourPassword" }'
```

Comment: Why this swagger rest api list isn't the same as the one here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html ?

Comment: In order to see the full api list, I needed to create an integration in the admin and grant that integration full access to all APIs, then use the token for that integration.  I was not able to see the full set of APIs using the admin user token even with a full control admin user.

Comment: That's right @MattB swagger depends on the permissions and type of the token.

Answer (score 4):

To see the full list of services you may want to generate a full permissions token from the admin panel.

1. log into admin panel
2. Navigate to Systems -> Integrations (under Extensions section)
3. click on "Add a new Integration" Button
4. Fill in the required fields and move to API tab on the left, for "*Resource Access*" select **All**
5. Hit save and in the grid view click on Authorize.
6. Grab the **Access Token** generated (and save the rest of the info, of course).
7. Navigate to /swagger and paste that access token to see the full list of REST services on your site.