# Modual to acceess API required?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am struggling with getting connected to a Magento site's API and getting permission denied. I have manually created an integration using the Admin GUI and activated it with all permissions, I then use the Access Key during my API calls.

Also tried to admin accounts, got there key's and still no joy!

Tested in code and SoapUI.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688130/getting-401-error-on-megento-2-1-10-using-access-token-with-an-intergration-user).

My feeling is that there is permission issues on the site.

So my question is do I have to create a module and register it as an add on so integration created when installing the module has the right file permissions and is able to access the API.

Thanks,
Richard.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the calls you are making and the information you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: Cheers Dominic, edited to include link to question on stackoverflow

Comment: Have you tried debugging using swagger https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/generate-local.html?

Comment: Yep the following message `Can't read swagger JSON from https://www.XXXXX.com/rest/default/schema?services=all` without or with one of the key's generated via the integration or admin accounts.

Comment: Is your site local? That could be a false positive https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138591/magento-2-not-loading-all-the-core-apis-in-swagger

Comment: I think I know what you mean but its a remote production site and unfortunately I don't have root access to the server just access to the Admin GUI so cant check logs unless there is a way to access logs through the GUI?